# How to avoid linux move error due to socket files?

Tags: linux, bash, mv

I have a `mv folder` line that displays a confusing message because there is one socket file inside this folder.

Is there a way to change it in such way that it will not display this error. I don't really care about this socket file because its lifespan is transient, I only need to be sure that I move (archive) the folder to another safe location.

```
mv /tmp/env-DkKZrr3 /home/user/some-path/
mv: cannot stat ‘/tmp/ir-venv-DkKZrr3/10.0.0.101-cloud-user’: No such file or directory
```

I know that I could redirect the stderr but I would prefer to only avoid or ignore these specific kind of error, no others.

Comment: Even if you got this warning, the other files got moved, right ?

Comment: @Aserre yes, that's just a warning but is confusing on CI logs and I want to avoid it.

Comment: If you just want to suppres all errors from `mv`, you can redirect the output of stderr :  `mv /tmp/env-DkKZrr3 /home/user/some-path/ 2>/dev/null`. However, this will erase all errors from `mv`, including permission errors.

Comment: `grep -v` on STDERR?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww That is unix shell programming, is valid on any of the mentioned sites, including stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot just "ignore" a certain type of error message. For your requirement, I think it could be a better way to check the file type before you `mv`.  You can check if a file is a socket by:

```
[ -S <yourFilePath> ]
```

Adding this check to your script, and if the result is `True`, you skip moving the file. I think it should be ok.

`Grep` trick here is not recommended IMO, because if you mv a non-exists file, the error message looks the same, you cannot distinguish it is really a non-exist error or a socket file error.